# How to create Replicated table for Join Engine

Tags: clickhouse

There are Replicated shards on the cluster, and due to I can't create a 'ReplicatedJoin' engine table, I create a Distributed Engine table(join_dist) on the Join Engine local table(join_local). After I insert data into local table by proxy, I do this query: select count(1) from join_dist and I find that its result is approximate a half of actual value. I think this query only collect half shards result of cluster. How can I solve this？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a multiplexing feature of Distributed table.

---

So you create an additional cluster remote_serves where all Clickhouse nodes a replicas in a single shard with internal_replication = false

Then you create a Distributed table using that new cluster.

Then you insert data into Distributed table and Distributed table multiplex inserts and write exactly the same data to all replicas (to all engine=Join tables).

Then you use select count(1) from join -- you don't need to use select count(1) from _dist because all join tables have the same data.